# Creating a new array from specific attribute of custom NSObject

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom NSObject called ListItem. I have an array filled with ListItems. One of the properties of a ListItem is it's name (among other things like id, creation date, etc.)

**My question:** Can I create a new array with only the names of all the ListItems? I would essentially be left with an Array of NSString's. Of course I could simple create a for loop, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
NSArray *array = ...
NSArray *names = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.name"];
```

This is a Key-Value Coding (KVC) Collection operator.

From [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/):

> @unionOfObjects / @distinctUnionOfObjects: Returns an array of the objects in the property specified in the key path to the right of the operator.

Comment: would unionOfObjects be the name of my array containing the listitem objects? So if I have an array named MyListItems filled with ListItems, I would do valueForKeyPath@"@MyListItems.name"

Comment: No, @unionOfObjects is an operator. Your `MyListItems` would be what I called `array`. There is no need to change the key path expression.

Comment: Just tried it and it works like a charm. Thanks mate this is unbelievably eloquent/awesome.

Comment: Read the article I linked on the answer. KVC operators are very powerful!